# react-leaflet add label/popup next to marker

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have been banging my head off the wall for 3 days and now decided to reach out for help…

I have a dataset that contains an ‘id’ and I would like to display that ‘id’ next to the marker or a replacement of the marker, this can be a label or popup or anything else I’m open to suggestions.

I looked at a lot of online examples and could not get any to work and worked out that most of this was due to me having a later version of react-leaflet, the old version exports ‘Map’ and the latest version exports ‘MapContainer’ so I tried to convert some online examples but still no joy.

Something like this image would be great!

[image: Something like this would be great]

```
import React from 'react'
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Polyline } from 'react-leaflet'
import L from "leaflet";
import "./App.css";


const customMarker = new L.icon({
    iconUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/images/marker-icon.png",
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [10, 41],
    popupAnchor: [2, -40]
});

const myData = JSON.parse('[{"id":3,"stopId":"STOPID-TA21 9AD~1536","coordinates":[[50.98115822630729,-3.2093097241813626]]},{"id":4,"stopId":"STOPID-EX4 8HH~1537","coordinates":[[50.73658088928259,-3.481135132172668]]},{"id":5,"stopId":"STOPID-EX3 0QH~1538","coordinates":[[50.68477425437021,-3.448725268717586]]},{"id":6,"stopId":"STOPID-TQ6 9LA~1539","coordinates":[[50.3528669555381,-3.600095665457003]]},{"id":7,"stopId":"STOPID-DE65 6BG~1542","coordinates":[[52.87354650871699,-1.5581688412757033]]},{"id":8,"stopId":"STOPID-NG20 9QU~1545","coordinates":[[53.217696,-1.1362328]]},{"id":9,"stopId":"STOPID-NG20 9QU~1548","coordinates":[[53.217696,-1.1362328]]},{"id":10,"stopId":"STOPID-NG20 9QU~1546","coordinates":[[53.21800641457751,-1.1354169130791034]]},{"id":11,"stopId":"STOPID-NP11 4ER~1554","coordinates":[[51.666329754845755,-3.1443305326604944]]},{"id":12,"stopId":"STOPID-NP23 7WJ~1555","coordinates":[[51.734530948192244,-3.178078655551782]]},{"id":13,"stopId":"STOPID-GL18 2AN~1532","coordinates":[[51.98455968622588,-2.445541072124886]]},{"id":14,"stopId":"STOPID-GL18 1BY~1531","coordinates":[[51.93142465831891,-2.407781870252181]]},{"id":15,"stopId":"STOPID-HR2 9AS~1533","coordinates":[[52.000714453292005,-2.7953236019870005]]},{"id":16,"stopId":"STOPID-HR4 7NH~1534","coordinates":[[52.092459099571236,-2.9051723608040594]]},{"id":17,"stopId":"STOPID-LD3 8NA~1535","coordinates":[[51.93748683342681,-3.4157228488264124]]},{"id":18,"stopId":"STOPID-HR8 2DH~1525","coordinates":[[52.0346525,-2.4365534]]},{"id":19,"stopId":"STOPID-HR8 2DH~1528","coordinates":[[52.0346525,-2.4365534]]},{"id":20,"stopId":"STOPID-HR8 2DH~1524","coordinates":[[52.034652760327226,-2.4365536678734805]]},{"id":21,"stopId":"STOPID-HR8 2XW~1523","coordinates":[[52.02880753462352,-2.429552550694105]]},{"id":22,"stopId":"STOPID-CF39 9DU~1556","coordinates":[[51.5983434,-3.4249801]]},{"id":23,"stopId":"STOPID-CF39 9DU~1557","coordinates":[[51.59803073699841,-3.423115687588953]]},{"id":24,"stopId":"STOPID-BN17 5QZ~1551","coordinates":[[50.81120291892175,-0.5873687372834572]]},{"id":25,"stopId":"STOPID-BN2 6AF~1552","coordinates":[[50.84513347167287,-0.08241743108671877]]},{"id":26,"stopId":"STOPID-WV1 1PN~1540","coordinates":[[52.59340809839608,-2.1244413046916635]]},{"id":27,"stopId":"STOPID-HR8 2DH~1527","coordinates":[[52.0346525,-2.4365534]]},{"id":28,"stopId":"STOPID-HR8 2DH~1529","coordinates":[[52.0346525,-2.4365534]]},{"id":29,"stopId":"STOPID-HR8 2DH~1526","coordinates":[[52.034652760327226,-2.4365536678734805]]},{"id":30,"stopId":"STOPID-CV3 4LH~1541","coordinates":[[52.39288327159674,-1.477401293729262]]},{"id":31,"stopId":"STOPID-LE18 2FT~1543","coordinates":[[52.588473356251626,-1.1238469402885252]]},{"id":32,"stopId":"STOPID-NG2 5HE~1544","coordinates":[[52.932301974273514,-1.1127634222678116]]},{"id":33,"stopId":"STOPID-NG20 9QU~1549","coordinates":[[53.217696,-1.1362328]]},{"id":34,"stopId":"STOPID-NG20 9QU~1547","coordinates":[[53.21800641457751,-1.1354169130791034]]},{"id":35,"stopId":"STOPID-NP16 6PS~1553","coordinates":[[51.69368874342044,-2.7321130647982597]]},{"id":36,"stopId":"STOPID-CF3 1TH~1530","coordinates":[[51.504294235355275,-3.119426476644571]]}]')

export default function App() {

    return (
        <MapContainer center={[52.6376, -1.135171]} zoom={7} >
            <TileLayer
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            />
            {myData.map(stop => (
                <Marker key={stop.id} position={stop.coordinates[0]} icon={customMarker}
                />
            ))}

        </MapContainer>
    );
}
```

[My Project](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-marker-from-json-n2om3)

[This project by Konstantinos would be good but cant get it to work in my project](https://codesandbox.io/s/cjziy?file=/src/index.js:96-143)

Comment: you can use `Popup` component inside `Marker` component. [example](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-popup-marker)

Comment: That's not what i was looking for, it needs looks like the sample image or similar, not just a popup. Thx for the response though...

Comment: I think you need maybe a [tooltip](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-tooltips) probably with custom style, because there is no marker in your example image

Comment: Hi kboul i think you created the original project that i tired to get working in my project which was https://codesandbox.io/s/cjziy?file=/src/index.js:96-143

Comment: Hi kboul, yes the answer was tooltip, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like in the comments posted you have to use `Tooltip`.

Implemented it looks like:

```
{myData.map((stop) => (
        <Marker
          key={stop.id}
          position={stop.coordinates[0]}
          icon={customMarker}
        >        
        <Tooltip direction="right" offset={[0, 0]} opacity={1} permanent>{stop.id}</Tooltip>
        </Marker>
      ))}
```

Also don't forget to add the import.

Result:

[image]

For more tooltip examples look into https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-tooltips.